# Reducing time required to login into sharepoint 2007 site

Tags: web-services, login

Can we reduce the time it takes after users enter their username and password into the dialog box that prompts up when we enter the website url?

For example, I try to enter a url in a sharepoint 2007 website -> it prompts for username and password -> I enter the username and passwords -> then it takes a long time to open the website.

Is there any way to reduce this time?

Comment: How slow is slow? Does it always take a fix number of seconds or does it vary? What kind of authentication mechanism do you use?

Answer (score 2):

Check if your hardware meets the SharePoint requirements specified in the SharePoint Deployment Guide.
Also a wake up script could reduce the load time for end users. There are various scripts available for free.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered bypassing the login diaglog completely by using the users windows login credentials ?

http://blog.fpweb.net/sharepoint-credentials-prompt-quick-tip/